# Application Monitor Error

Tags: windows-10

Hello I am trying to run a program called Application Monitor in windows 10. It can be downloaded here:

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/1913/

After installing I get a weird CEF binaries missing! error.

Here is a picture. [sorry file is too large to upload and imgur wouldn't link]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBqNY.jpg

Not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your image is no longer available ...

Answer (score 0):

#### I am trying to run a program called Application Monitor in windows 10

Application Monitor is an old program dating back to 2005.

> SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS:
>
> Operating System: Windows 98 - ME - NT 4(service pack5) - 2000 - WindowsXP

Source: [Application Monitor - checks running programs](http://www.jockersoft.com/english/appmonitor_index.php)

Having said that it does work on Window7.

> After installing I get a weird CEF binaries missing! error.

You might want to try some of the other 7 programs listed at [8 Tools to Automatically Restart a Crashed or Closed Application • Raymond.CC](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/keep-application-running-by-automatically-rerun-when-closed/view-all/)

There is also a batch file solution - see [windows 10 - Auto-restart an executable after the application crashes - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1362291/auto-restart-an-executable-after-the-application-crashes)

Comment: I did, I also got the same error 5 other times.

Comment: @user1257665 Have you tried [Automatically Restart Crashed Or Hanged Applications | W-Shadow.com](https://w-shadow.com/blog/2009/03/04/restart-on-crash/) - that was last updated just over a year ago ...

Comment: @user1257665 There is also a batch file solution - [windows 10 - Auto-restart an executable after the application crashes - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1362291/auto-restart-an-executable-after-the-application-crashes)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried restart on crash. I got the same error. I think I'm missing some packages, but which ones I have no idea. I also tried the batch file. I got the same error. Something is missing in windows.